# fstream won't create a file

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

I'm simply trying to create a text file if it does not exist and I can't seem to get `fstream` to do this.

```
#include <fstream>
using std::fstream;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    fstream file;
    file.open("test.txt");
    file << "test";
    file.close();
}
```

Do I need to specify anything in the `open()` function in order to get it to create the file? I've read that you can't specify `ios::in` as that will expect an already existing file to be there, but I'm unsure if other parameters need to be specified for a file that does not already exist.

Comment: I think you have to use: .open ("test.txt", fstream::in);

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should add fstream::out to open method like this:

```
file.open("test.txt",fstream::out);
```

More information about fstream flags, check out this link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/

Comment: Am I not allowed to do `file.open("test.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::binary);` on a file that does not yet exist?

Comment: You should add fstream::trunc if you want fstream::in to work on an non-existent file.

Comment: @haitaka Is it a workaround? Because it seems illogical: in order to make a stream from a created file `in` I have to truncate the stream.

Answer (score 17):

You need to add some arguments. Also, instancing and opening can be put in one line:

```
fstream file("test.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc);
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using std::fstream;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    fstream file;
    file.open("test.txt",std::ios::out);
    file << fflush;
    file.close();
}
```