# fstream counterpart to O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND

Tags: c++, fstream

I want to create file if it doesn't exist, or append to the end if it does, but also be able to read:

```
 std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::ate
```

The current answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835888/stdfstream-doesnt-create-file) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667530/fstream-wont-create-a-file) all suggest I can either get rid of the ability to read the file, or truncate it. [Google](https://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/131992-stl-fstream-o_rdwr-o_creat) provides one post that scolds the asker for not finding another post which is long gone along with its author and "hints" it's a two-step process...

Comment: isn't the second answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835888/stdfstream-doesnt-create-file) not an option for you?

Comment: @bkVnet: Answers have no inherent ordering. The ordering you see may be different for someone else, and will change over time. Best to identify answers by direct URL or by author's name.

Comment: Congratulations on 5,555 rep :D

Comment: @bkVnet: Won't that truncate the file if exists but its current permissions are 'write only'? (e.g. UNIX chmod 222)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Thanks. I edited the tags of the linked question - lack of 'fstream' was what probably made me miss it. As for 5555, I was above that last week, then I found an answer for a question about something *extremely* annoying me, and mere +10 karma for its author wouldn't cut it :)

Comment: @SF Yes it does. but according to the documentation for [std::basic_filebuf::open](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) you can uses `std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app` since this combination will create a file if it doesn't exit.

Comment: @SF. [tag:fstream] is a pretty terrible tag.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: iostream is only about standard input/output. I wouldn't think about looking for file operations under it.

Comment: @SF No, file streams are part of the I/O Streams library.