# How to make sure file exists and it is opened

Tags: c++, fstream

I am trying to make a program which checks if a file exists, otherwise it creates and opens it. This is what I tried doing:

```
fstream file("data.txt");
if (!file.is_open())
{
    ofstream file("data.txt");
    file.close();
}
fstream file("data.txt");
```

The program tries to open the data.txt file and if it does not exist, it creates it, but then it is a local variable in the if statement, so I have to close and open it in the main function. If the file already exists then I get a multiple instances error.
I tried closing the file before opening it but it still gives me the same error. Code:

```
fstream file("data.txt");
if (!file.is_open())
{
    ofstream file("data.txt");
    file.close();
}
file.close();
fstream file("data.txt");
```

Is there a better way to do it than that?
Thx for your time =)
(yes, I have searched for answers before asking.)

Comment: Search before asking: * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667530/fstream-wont-create-a-file
* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835888/stdfstream-doesnt-create-file

Comment: also the constructor isnt the only way to open a file with a stream, you can call open as well.

Comment: @GangYin I did not search fstream won't create a file. Obviously this wasn't my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a file stream without specifying without telling which file to open.

```
fstream file;
file.open("data.txt");
```

Then use `.fail()` to check if it has **FAILED** in opening the file

```
if (fileStream.fail()) 
{
    ofstream file("data.txt");
}
file.open("data.txt");
```

Then open it again. fstream (Filestream) is just simply a child of iostream which does not required to be initialized and can be declared you can read more about it over [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: All good, just mark my answer as accepted and upvote so it will help others in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Also this is c and POSIX - maybe it is of interest, cause it is a fast and handy check if file exists.

```
#include <unistd.h>
if(access(filename, F_OK ) == 1) // file exists
...
```

Comment: This unfortunately results in a [TOCTTOU bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use).